# Understanding socket timeout when using okhttp-sse

Tags: java, okhttp, server-sent-events

I'm using okhttp-sse to consume server side events in Java.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
String sseUrl = getSseUrl();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(sseUrl)
    .build();
EventSource.Factory factory = EventSources.createFactory(httpClient);
factory.newEventSource(request, listener);
```

This works and I receive events, but it fails after 10 seconds due to a SocketTimeoutException. I discovered that okhttp has a default timeout of 10 seconds, so this makes sense.

I increased the timeouts on my client to 1 minute, but now I get that SocketTimeoutException after 3 minutes. I don't understand what is going on. I would have expected the timeout after 1 minute.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build();
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What version are you using? For version 3, your settings look correct https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-3.0.0/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.java#L386 , are you sure you are using version3

Comment: I'm using okhttp3 4.11.0 and okhttp-sse 4.11.0

Comment: I ended up setting the timeouts to 0 to indicate no timeout, which I think makes sense for SSE. So maybe my question isn't important, but still curious behavior that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for okhttp-sse is to set the timeouts to `0` to indicate no timeout.

```
OkHttpClient sseHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // no timeout
    .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // no timeout
    .writeTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // no timeout
    .build();
```